# Image styles not working in Drupal on fresh install

Tags: php, image, drupal

On a fresh install of Drupal 7.36 on ubuntu 14.04 served using Php's built-in server, I cannot get the image styles to work, the files are not being created. I checked permissions and it's all good, the full-size image itself is being uploaded to the correct location. How can I get the image thumbnails to be generated and work ?

Comment: error reporting? errors?

Comment: I can't remember but I don't think the images for the styles are generated until you use it. Change the field display to the image style then see if it shows up.

Answer (score 1):

It's probably missing one of the images libraries it uses to adjust the images, like gd.

Check your Status Report (/admin/reports/status) to check. If so, you'll just need to [install the libraries on Ubuntu](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-or-add-php-gd-support-to-apache/) and should be good.